# Reactjs - Call function on startup of application with a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

My application displays a greeting such as *"Good Morning"* depending on the time of day. I have a function that checks the time and changes the greeting based on what time it is. I can't use `componentDidMount` since it's a functional component, so I'm using `React.useEffect`. The issue is this does not run on startup, there is a small delay where the app displays "Good Morning" and then will change to *"Good Afternoon"*. How can I remove this delay.

**Function that determines greeting based on time**

```
const [currGreeting, setCurrGreeting] = useState(greetings[0]);

//Involves saving to localStorage so the transition can be seamless if the app is exited and returned to

function updateGreeting(){
  time = new Date();
    
  let hour = time.getHours();

  console.log(hour);

  if(12 > hour && hour > 5){
    setCurrGreeting(greetings[0]);
    console.log("Good Morning")

    const curSessionGreeting = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sessionGreeting")) || [];
    if(curSessionGreeting != currGreeting){
      localStorage.setItem("sessionGreeting", JSON.stringify(greetings[0]));
      setCurrGreeting(greetings[0]);
    }
  }
  if((18 > hour && hour > 12) || hour === 12){
    setCurrGreeting(greetings[1]);
    console.log("Good Afternoon")

    const curSessionGreeting = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sessionGreeting")) || [];
    if(curSessionGreeting != currGreeting){
      localStorage.setItem("sessionGreeting", JSON.stringify(greetings[1]));
      setCurrGreeting(greetings[1]);
    }
  }
  if(hour > 18 || (5 > hour && hour > 0)){
    setCurrGreeting(greetings[2]);
    console.log("Good Evening")

    const curSessionGreeting = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sessionGreeting")) || [];
    if(curSessionGreeting != currGreeting){
      localStorage.setItem("sessionGreeting", JSON.stringify(greetings[2]));
      setCurrGreeting(greetings[2]);
    }
  }
}
```

**Updates the greeting**

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(()=>updateGreeting(), 1000);
});
```

**Where the app is rendering**

```
return (
<div> 
  <div style = {{display: 'flex', fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontSize: 25,marginBottom: 25, color: '#CDCACA'}}>
    <text>{currGreeting}</text>
   </div> 
 </div> 
 );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: where's the functional component?

Comment: This is within function App(){, which I render using ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: pleas share it and explain the components structure

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I added how it renders, there is a lot of other code so I simplified it. The main thing to consider is that previously React used classes but I am using a functional component to render my application so that I can use the new form of hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run one `updateGreeting` before executing `setInterval` since this delay the first `updateGreeting` execution one second `1000ms`it does that asynchronously :

```
React.useEffect(() => {

   updateGreeting()//first execution
  
   setInterval(()=>updateGreeting(), 1000);
},[]);
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, out of curiosity how often will updateGreeting run on the first call? I understand the one based on interval but not the initial call.

Comment: for the first time it also wait 1 second to run that method, it's an asynchronous behavior,  the code after `=>` will be executed in future in this case after 1s, so to avoid that we add a synchronous code before that